# Ubuntu 14.04 fails to boot on restart or cold-start , grub appears on Ctrl+Alt+Del

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 with encrypted installation and encrypted home folder. But my Ubuntu fails to boot in restart or cold-start.I see the power LED burning but no HDD LED activity.If I press Ctrl+Alt+Del or press the restart button on my tower( out of frustration, I am a Windows user) I see the grub, sometime with 800*600 resolution or sometime with 1152*864 resolution. This is a fresh installation. Why it is happening so.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem recently with same setup (encryption). Seemed like every second boot failed with same effect as in your case. Workaround was going to TTY1-6 and back to TTY7.
Then I fixed it by disabling splash screen from grub config (open */etc/default/grub* with text editor, and remove *splash* option from this line: *GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT*). Then run update-grub.

Comment: I am unable to save after erasing "quiet splash". Says you do not have enough privilege.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention this have to be done as root. So you can type in terminal: sudo gedit /etc/default/grub and after that you'll be able to save changes. Then update-grub. Also, just remove the splash.

Comment: should i run sudo update-grub ?

Comment: Yes, update-grub should be run with a root privilege, so "sudo update-grub" it is.

Comment: Yes it has worked but I have lost my GUI interface to key in my encryption passphrase. Now I have a CUI screen where I put in my passphrase. Why is it so. Does it happen in every system. ?

Comment: Yeah, that's the effect of disabling the splash screen. You see CLI instead of fancy graphics. I'm not sure about the root of the problem, perhaps the graphics driver cannot access some needed config file on root partition since it's encrypted while the splash screen is shown. But that's just my assumption. So if you want the splash screen, my solution is still just workaround for the whole thing. Good luck finding a real one, if you'll be continuing your search ;)